# Upgraded from Angular 12 to 15 and Node.js v12 to v16.20.1 and getting translate and other errors while lazy loading modules

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, angular-material, bootstrap-5

I have an [Angular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_(web_framework)) project that was working perfectly fine, but I had to upgrade to Node.js version 16.20.1 from version 12 to get the OpenAI API to work.

I am running into multiple issues, including it not saying shared module not found and no pipe found for translate.

Although I fixed most issues, there are still some I cannot solve and after extensive research, I could not find anyone with similar issues or fixes.

It is failing to find material tags, translation pipes, template classes and even ngClass tags. I tried disabling [Angular Ivy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_(web_framework)#History), but I didn't have any luck. I also removed and reinstalled all Node.js modules and cleared the cache. Is there something I am doing wrong or forgetting?

I think bootstrap is not working or loading properly after the update, but no matter what I tried, I cannot get it to load and work.

How can I solve this issue? My shared module and another module that shows lazy loading are posted below.

The project works fine on Node.js version 12.12, but I need to upgrade to version 16 to use the OpenAI library.

The issue seems to be with the Angular Ivy compiler. Is there a way to disable it or fix the build for Angular Ivy?

Some of the error I am getting are:

```
Error: node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/accordion/accordion.d.ts:115:74 - error TS2344: Type '{ disabled: { alias: "disabled"; required: false; }; id: { alias: "id"; required: false; }; title: { alias: "title"; required: false; }; type: { alias: "type"; required: false; }; cardClass: { alias: "cardClass"; required: false; }; }' does not satisfy the constraint '{ [key: string]: string; }'.
  Property '"disabled"' is incompatible with index signature.
    Type '{ alias: "disabled"; required: false; }' is not assignable to type 'string'.

115     static ɵdir: i0.ɵɵDirectiveDeclaration<NgbPanel, "ngb-panel", never, { "disabled": { "alias": "disabled"; "required": false; }; "id": { "alias": "id"; "required": false; }; "title": { "alias": "title"; "required": false; }; "type": { "alias": "type"; "required": false; }; "cardClass": { "alias": "cardClass"; "required": false; }; }, { "shown": "shown"; "hidden": "hidden"; }, ["titleTpls", "headerTpls", "contentTpls"], never, true, never>;

Error: src/app/login/register/register.component.html:10:18 - error NG8002: Can't bind to 'ngClass' since it isn't a known property of 'input'.

10                  [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.firstName.errors }">
                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Error: src/app/sidebar-menu/admin-dashboard/waiter-menu/table-summary/table-summary.component.html:5:35 - error NG8004: No pipe found with name 'translate'.

5     <h2>{{ 'tableSummary.title' | translate }}</h2>
                                    ~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/sidebar-menu/admin-dashboard/waiter-menu/table-summary/table-summary.component.ts:19:16
    19   templateUrl: './table-summary.component.html',
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component TableSummaryComponent.


Error: src/app/sidebar-menu/table/games/chess/chess.component.html:3:28 - error NG8004: No pipe found with name 'translate'.

3   <h2>{{ 'sidebar.games' | translate }}</h2>
                             ~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/sidebar-menu/table/games/chess/chess.component.ts:7:16
    7   templateUrl: './chess.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component ChessComponent.


Error: src/app/sidebar-menu/table/games/games.component.html:3:28 - error NG8004: No pipe found with name 'translate'.

3   <h2>{{ 'sidebar.games' | translate }}</h2>
                             ~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/sidebar-menu/table/games/games.component.ts:7:16
    7   templateUrl: './games.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component GamesComponent.


Error: src/app/sidebar-menu/table/order-history/order-history.component.html:2:3 - error NG8001: 'alert' is not a known element:
1. If 'alert' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. To allow any element add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.

2   <alert></alert>
    ~~~~~~~

  src/app/sidebar-menu/table/order-history/order-history.component.ts:24:16
    24   templateUrl: './order-history.component.html',
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component OrderHistoryComponent.


Error: src/app/upload-image-dialog/upload-image-dialog.component.html:12:3 - error NG8001: 'mat-dialog-content' is not a known element:
1. If 'mat-dialog-content' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-dialog-content' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

12   <mat-dialog-content>
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/upload-image-dialog/upload-image-dialog.component.ts:14:16
    14   templateUrl: './upload-image-dialog.component.html',
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component UploadImageDialogComponent.


Error: src/app/upload-image-dialog/upload-image-dialog.component.html:16:5 - error NG8001: 'mat-form-field' is not a known element:
1. If 'mat-form-field' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-form-field' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

16     <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/upload-image-dialog/upload-image-dialog.component.ts:14:16
    14   templateUrl: './upload-image-dialog.component.html',
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component UploadImageDialogComponent.


Error: src/app/upload-image-dialog/upload-image-dialog.component.html:30:3 - error NG8001: 'mat-dialog-actions' is not a known element:
1. If 'mat-dialog-actions' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-dialog-actions' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

30   <mat-dialog-actions>
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/upload-image-dialog/upload-image-dialog.component.ts:14:16
    14   templateUrl: './upload-image-dialog.component.html',
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component UploadImageDialogComponent.


Error: src/app/upload-image-dialog/upload-image-dialog.component.html:33:142 - error NG8004: No pipe found with name 'translate'.

33       <button [disabled]="submitted" (click)="delete()" mdbBtn color="danger" block="true" class="my-4 right-margin-set">{{ 'Delete Image' | translate }}</button>
                                                                                                                                                ~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/upload-image-dialog/upload-image-dialog.component.ts:14:16
    14   templateUrl: './upload-image-dialog.component.html',
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component UploadImageDialogComponent.


Error: src/app/upload-image-dialog/upload-image-dialog.component.html:34:121 - error NG8004: No pipe found with name 'translate'.

34       <button [disabled]="submitted" (click)="save()" mdbBtn color="info" block="true" class="my-4">{{ 'Update Image' | translate }}</button>
                                                                                                                           ~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/upload-image-dialog/upload-image-dialog.component.ts:14:16
    14   templateUrl: './upload-image-dialog.component.html',
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component UploadImageDialogComponent.


Error: src/orderUser/order-user/order-user.component.html:7:39 - error NG8004: No pipe found with name 'translate'.

7             <h2>{{'orderUser.title' | translate }}</h2>
                                        ~~~~~~~~~

  src/orderUser/order-user/order-user.component.ts:22:18
    22     templateUrl: './order-user.component.html',
                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component OrderUserComponent.


Error: src/orderUser/order-user/order-user.component.html:29:5 - error NG8001: 'alert' is not a known element:
1. If 'alert' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. To allow any element add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.

29     <alert></alert>
       ~~~~~~~

  src/orderUser/order-user/order-user.component.ts:22:18
    22     templateUrl: './order-user.component.html',
                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component OrderUserComponent.


Error: src/paymentUser/payment-user/payment-user.component.html:33:5 - error NG8001: 'alert' is not a known element:
1. If 'alert' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. To allow any element add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.

33     <alert></alert>
       ~~~~~~~

  src/paymentUser/payment-user/payment-user.component.ts:32:16
    32   templateUrl: './payment-user.component.html',
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component PaymentUserComponent.


Error: Can't resolve 'node_modules/chartist/dist/chartist.css' in '/Users/shahzibsarfraz/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Desktop/REPO/Dine-N-Go'



  Error: src/app/sidebar-menu/admin-dashboard/profiles/edit-admin-user/edit-admin-user.component.html:8:9 - error NG8001: 'mat-tab' is not a known element:
1. If 'mat-tab' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-tab' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

8         <mat-tab label="Create Profiles">
          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

✖ Failed to compile.
```

I am lazy loading modules and my [package.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/configuring-npm/package-json/) file is:

```javascript
{
  "name": "DineNGo",
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "browser": {
    "fs": false,
    "path": false,
    "os": false
  },
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "main": "server.js",
    "heroku-postbuild": "ng build --aot --configuration=${ENV}",
    "preinstall": "npm install --location=global @angular/cli @angular/compiler-cli --legacy-peer-deps",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "cypress:open": "cypress open",
    "cypress:run": "cypress run",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^15.2.0",
    "@angular/animations": "^15.2.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^15.2.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^15.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^15.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~15.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~15.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^15.2.0",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^15.0.0-beta.42",
    "@angular/forms": "^15.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^15.2.0",
    "@angular/localize": "^15.2.0",
    "@angular/material": "^15.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "15.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "15.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "15.2.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^15.1.2",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "^15.2.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "13.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.8",
    "@types/chart.js": "^2.9.39",
    "@types/chartist": "^0.11.0",
    "@types/crypto-js": "^4.1.3",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.20",
    "@types/jasmine": "~5.1.1",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.12",
    "@types/lodash": "4.14.200",
    "@types/node": "^20.8.10",
    "@types/popper.js": "^1.11.0",
    "@types/socket.io": "^3.0.2",
    "@types/socket.io-client": "^3.0.0",
    "@types/uuid": "^9.0.6",
    "@types/w3c-web-usb": "^1.0.9",
    "@types/web-bluetooth": "0.0.19",
    "ajv": "^8.12.0",
    "angular-bootstrap-md": "^15.0.0",
    "angular-cc-library": "^3.2.0",
    "angular-cli-ghpages": "^1.0.7",
    "angular-notifier": "^14.0.0",
    "angular-responsive-carousel": "^2.1.2",
    "angular5-csv": "^0.2.11",
    "angularx-qrcode": "^11.0.0",
    "apexcharts": "^3.44.0",
    "axios": "^1.6.0",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.20.2",
    "bootstrap": "^5.3.2",
    "chart.js": "^4.4.0",
    "chartist": "^1.3.0",
    "config": "^3.3.9",
    "core-js": "^2.6.12",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "crypto": "^1.0.1",
    "crypto-js": "^4.2.0",
    "css-loader": "^6.8.1",
    "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
    "exec": "^0.2.1",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "fontawesome": "^5.6.3",
    "fs": "^0.0.1-security",
    "got": "^13.0.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.2",
    "jwt-decode": "^4.0.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "lz-string": "^1.5.0",
    "material-dashboard": "^3.0.9",
    "material-design-icons": "^3.0.1",
    "material-design-lite": "^1.3.0",
    "mdbootstrap": "^4.20.0",
    "mongodb": "^6.2.0",
    "mongoose": "^8.0.0",
    "ng-apexcharts": "1.8.0",
    "ng-chartist": "^8.1.3",
    "ng-multiselect-dropdown": "^1.0.0",
    "ng-socket-io": "^0.2.4",
    "ng2-charts": "^5.0.3",
    "ngx-autosize": "^2.0.4",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^11.0.2",
    "ngx-chess-board": "2.2.3",
    "ngx-device-detector": "^6.0.2",
    "ngx-guided-tour": "^2.0.1",
    "ngx-swiper-wrapper": "^10.0.0",
    "openai": "^4.15.0",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "postcss": "^8.4.31",
    "remote-pay-cloud": "4.1.2",
    "remote-pay-cloud-api": "4.0.5",
    "resize-base64": "^1.0.12",
    "rootpath": "^0.1.2",
    "rxjs": "^7.8.1",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.6.7",
    "socket.io": "^4.7.2",
    "socket.io-client": "^4.7.2",
    "time-ago-pipe": "^1.3.2",
    "ts-node": "10.9.1",
    "tslib": "^2.6.2",
    "typescript": "4.9.3",
    "uuid": "^9.0.1",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.2",
    "zone.js": "~0.14.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/core": "^15.2.0",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "^15.2.0",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.2",
    "cypress": "^13.4.0",
    "cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": "^4.3.1",
    "cypress-multi-reporters": "^1.6.4",
    "eslint-plugin-cypress": "^2.15.1",
    "express-jwt": "^8.4.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~5.1.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~7.0.0",
    "karma": "^6.4.2",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^2.1.0",
    "ng2-charts-schematics": "^0.1.7",
    "protractor": "^7.0.0",
    "swiper": "^6.8.4",
    "tslint": "~6.1.3"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "16.20.1",
    "npm": "8.1.0"
  }
}
```

Shared module:

```javascript
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import {TranslateLoader, TranslateModule, TranslateService} from '@ngx-translate/core';
import {HttpClient, HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';
import {TranslateHttpLoader} from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';
import {AlertComponent} from './directives';
import {AlertService} from '../_services';
import {MatFormFieldModule} from '@angular/material/form-field';
import {MatInputModule} from '@angular/material/input';
import {FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {MatDatepickerModule} from '@angular/material/datepicker';
import {MatNativeDateModule} from '@angular/material/core';
import {TimeAgoPipe} from 'time-ago-pipe';
import {MatButtonToggleModule} from '@angular/material/button-toggle';
import {MatTooltipModule} from '@angular/material/tooltip';
import {MatSelectModule} from '@angular/material/select';
import {NgApexchartsModule} from 'ng-apexcharts';
import { MatTabsModule } from '@angular/material/tabs';
import {MatCardModule} from '@angular/material/card';
import {NotifierModule, NotifierOptions} from 'angular-notifier';
import {DragDropModule} from '@angular/cdk/drag-drop';
import {CartListComponent} from './components/cart-list/cart-list.component';
import {MatProgressSpinnerModule} from '@angular/material/progress-spinner';
import {MatTableModule} from '@angular/material/table';
import {MatChipsModule} from '@angular/material/chips';
import {AutosizeModule} from 'ngx-autosize';
import {GuidedTourModule} from 'ngx-guided-tour';
import {MatIconModule} from '@angular/material/icon';
import {MatCheckboxModule} from '@angular/material/checkbox';
import {MatSortModule} from '@angular/material/sort';
import {RouterModule} from '@angular/router';
import {MatDividerModule} from '@angular/material/divider';
import {MatPaginatorModule} from '@angular/material/paginator';
import {MatSlideToggleModule} from '@angular/material/slide-toggle';
import {MatRadioModule} from '@angular/material/radio';
import {MatExpansionModule} from '@angular/material/expansion';
import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import {MDBBootstrapModule} from 'angular-bootstrap-md';
import {MatToolbarModule} from '@angular/material/toolbar';
import {MatListModule} from '@angular/material/list';
import {FlexLayoutModule} from '@angular/flex-layout';
import {DropdownUserRolesComponent} from './components/dropdown-user-roles/dropdown-user-roles.component';
import {MatDialogModule} from '@angular/material/dialog';
import {CustomMessageItemDialogComponent} from './components/custom-message-item-dialog/custom-message-item-dialog.component';
import {NotificationConfirmationComponent} from './components/notification-confirmation-component/notification-confirmation.component';
import {ItemOptionsDialogComponentComponent} from './components/item-options-dialog-component/item-options-dialog-component.component';
import {NotificationPopupComponent} from './components/notification-popup/notification-popup.component';
import {UploadImageDialogComponent} from '../upload-image-dialog/upload-image-dialog.component';
import {DropdownLanguageSelectorComponent} from './components/dropdown-language-selector/dropdown-language-selector.component';
import {DropdownBooleanSelectorComponent} from './components/dropdown-boolean-selector/dropdown-boolean-selector.component';
import {DropdownCategoriesComponent} from './components/dropdown-categories/dropdown-categories.component';
import {DropdownFilterByCategorySelectorComponent} from './components/dropdown-filter-by-category-selector/dropdown-filter-by-category-selector.component';
import {DropdownFilterByItemSelectorComponent} from './components/dropdown-filter-by-item-selector/dropdown-filter-by-item-selector.component';
import {MatSidenavModule} from '@angular/material/sidenav';
import {LoginModule} from '../login/login.module';
import {LoginComponent} from '../login/login';
import {LogoutComponent} from '../login/logout/logout.component';
import {RegisterComponent} from '../login/register';
import {SwiperModule} from "swiper/angular";
import { RatingsComponent } from './components/ratings-conponent/ratings.component';
import { QrGeneratorComponent } from './components/qr-generator/qr-generator.component';
import {QRCodeModule} from "angularx-qrcode";
import { OptionsSlideSelectorComponent } from './components/options-slide-selector/options-slide-selector.component';
import {SWIPER_CONFIG, SwiperConfigInterface} from "ngx-swiper-wrapper";
import { RoleSelectComponent } from '../login/role-select/role-select.component';
import { NgMultiSelectDropDownModule } from 'ng-multiselect-dropdown';
import {QrPayPopupComponent} from './components/qr-pay-popup/qr-pay-popup.component';
import {NotificationAndImagePopupComponent} from './components/notification-and-image-popup/notification-and-image-popup.component';
import {
    NotificationPaymentRequiredQrPopupComponent
} from './components/notification-payment-required-qr-popup/notification-payment-required-qr-popup.component';

const DEFAULT_SWIPER_CONFIG: SwiperConfigInterface = {
  direction: 'horizontal',
  slidesPerView: 'auto'
};

const customNotifierOptions: NotifierOptions = {
  position: {
    horizontal: {
      position: 'right',
      distance: 12
    },
    vertical: {
      position: 'top',
      distance: 60,
      gap: 10
    }
  },
  theme: 'material',
  behaviour: {
    autoHide: 5000,
    onClick: 'hide',
    onMouseover: 'pauseAutoHide',
    showDismissButton: true,
    stacking: 4
  },
  animations: {
    enabled: true,
    show: {
      preset: 'slide',
      speed: 300,
      easing: 'ease'
    },
    hide: {
      preset: 'fade',
      speed: 300,
      easing: 'ease',
      offset: 50
    },
    shift: {
      speed: 300,
      easing: 'ease'
    },
    overlap: 150
  }
};

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AlertComponent, TimeAgoPipe, CartListComponent, DropdownUserRolesComponent, CustomMessageItemDialogComponent,
    NotificationConfirmationComponent, NotificationPopupComponent, ItemOptionsDialogComponentComponent, UploadImageDialogComponent,
    DropdownLanguageSelectorComponent, DropdownBooleanSelectorComponent, DropdownCategoriesComponent, NotificationAndImagePopupComponent,
    DropdownFilterByCategorySelectorComponent, DropdownFilterByItemSelectorComponent, LoginComponent, RoleSelectComponent, QrPayPopupComponent,
    LogoutComponent, ItemOptionsDialogComponentComponent, RegisterComponent, RatingsComponent, QrGeneratorComponent, OptionsSlideSelectorComponent,
    NotificationPaymentRequiredQrPopupComponent],
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        NgMultiSelectDropDownModule.forRoot(),
        TranslateModule.forChild({
            loader: {
                provide: TranslateLoader,
                useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
                deps: [HttpClient]
            }
        }),
        MDBBootstrapModule.forRoot(),
        MatFormFieldModule,
        MatInputModule,
        FlexLayoutModule,
        MatDatepickerModule,
        MatDialogModule,
        SwiperModule,
        MatToolbarModule,
        MatNativeDateModule,
        MatSidenavModule,
        MatTooltipModule,
        MatSelectModule,
        MatTabsModule,
        MatListModule,
        MatButtonToggleModule,
        MatTableModule,
        NgApexchartsModule,
        MatCardModule,
        MatProgressSpinnerModule,
        NotifierModule.withConfig(customNotifierOptions),
        DragDropModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        MatChipsModule,
        AutosizeModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        FormsModule,
        GuidedTourModule,
        MatIconModule,
        MatCheckboxModule,
        MatSortModule,
        LoginModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        RouterModule,
        MatDividerModule,
        MatPaginatorModule,
        MatSlideToggleModule,
        MatRadioModule,
        MatExpansionModule,
        NgbModule,
        QRCodeModule,
    ],
  entryComponents: [
    ItemOptionsDialogComponentComponent,
    NotificationPopupComponent,
    NotificationPaymentRequiredQrPopupComponent,
    NotificationAndImagePopupComponent,
    QrPayPopupComponent,
    NotificationConfirmationComponent,
    UploadImageDialogComponent,
  ],
  exports: [
    TranslateModule,
    NgMultiSelectDropDownModule,
    MDBBootstrapModule,
    AlertComponent,
    MatIconModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatSortModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    RouterModule,
    MatDividerModule,
    MatPaginatorModule,
    MatSlideToggleModule,
    MatTabsModule,
    MatRadioModule,
    NgbModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatListModule,
    FlexLayoutModule,
    MatButtonToggleModule,
    MatExpansionModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatProgressSpinnerModule,
    FormsModule,
    MatTableModule,
    DragDropModule,
    SwiperModule,
    LoginModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatNativeDateModule,
    TimeAgoPipe,
    MatTooltipModule,
    MatSidenavModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    NgApexchartsModule,
    MatCardModule,
    NotifierModule,
    CartListComponent,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    MatChipsModule,
    AutosizeModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    GuidedTourModule,
    DropdownUserRolesComponent,
    NotificationConfirmationComponent,
    NotificationAndImagePopupComponent,
    NotificationPaymentRequiredQrPopupComponent,
    DropdownCategoriesComponent,
    NotificationPopupComponent,
    QrPayPopupComponent,
    CustomMessageItemDialogComponent,
    DropdownLanguageSelectorComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    LogoutComponent,
    RegisterComponent,
    ItemOptionsDialogComponentComponent,
    DropdownBooleanSelectorComponent,
    DropdownFilterByCategorySelectorComponent,
    DropdownFilterByItemSelectorComponent,
    RatingsComponent,
    QrGeneratorComponent,
    OptionsSlideSelectorComponent,

  ],
  providers: [
    AlertService,
    TranslateService,
    {
      provide: SWIPER_CONFIG,
      useValue: DEFAULT_SWIPER_CONFIG
    }
  ]
})
export class SharedModule { }
export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, '../../../assets/i18n/', '.json');
}
```

And the table module is:

```javascript
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import {SharedModule} from '../../shared/shared.module';
import {OrderHistoryComponent} from './order-history/order-history.component';
import {RouterModule, Routes} from '@angular/router';
import {ChessComponent} from './games/chess/chess.component';
import {AuthGuard} from '../../_guards/index';
import {NgxChessBoardModule} from 'ngx-chess-board';
import {GamesComponent} from "./games/games.component";


const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'orderHistory',
    component: OrderHistoryComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  },
  {
    path: 'games',
    loadChildren: () => import('./games/games.module').then(m => m.GamesModule),
    children:
    [
      {
        path: '',
        component: GamesComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuard]
      },
      {
        path: 'chess',
        component: ChessComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuard]
      },
      {
        path: 'ticTacToe',
        loadChildren: () => import('./games/tic-tac-toe/tic-tac-toe.module').then(m => m.TicTacToeModule),
        canActivate: [AuthGuard]
      },
    ],
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  },


];
@NgModule({
  declarations: [OrderHistoryComponent, ChessComponent, GamesComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    NgxChessBoardModule.forRoot(),
    RouterModule.forChild(routes),
  ]
})
export class TableModule { }
```

Comment: if you import SharedModule in TableModule Import Does this solve your issue?imports: [
    CommonModule,
    NgxChessBoardModule.forRoot(),
    RouterModule.forChild(routes),
  ]

Comment: Nope, I initally had it in there but then I got shared module has no export ng module.

Comment: [Why you shouldn't use a `SharedModule`](https://medium.com/@huannx.dev/stop-using-shared-module-in-angular-f003d8f61afa)

Comment: Your modules look fine to me tbh. I would do the upgrade version by version and understand in which version the issue appears. Check the official guide https://update.angular.io/?v=12.0-15.0